# Callback is undefined and other stories

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-callback

I got the following script, which is not working propperly. I know about getJSON's async nature, so I tried to build a callback function (`jsonConsoleLog`), which is supposed to be executed before getJSON get asigned to var (`myJson = json;`). After running debug in Chrome, I got two things out: A) debug is highlighting `jsonConsoleLog`calls inside getJSON function as `undefined`.
B) Console is throwing `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null` for `var friends = myJSON[0].friends;`, which means the whole function doesn't work.
I'm in battle with it since saturday and I really don't know what to do. There's clearly something up with my callback function, but shoot me if I know what. Help?

```
var myJSON = null;
var main = document.getElementsByClassName('main');
var sec = document.getElementsByClassName('sec');

function getJSON(jsonConsoleLog){
  $.getJSON('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cpldILZRfm?   indent=2', function(json){
    if (json != null){
        console.log('Load Successfull!');
    };
    if (jsonConsoleLog){
        jsonConsoleLog(json[0].friends);
    }
    myJSON = json;
  });   
};

function jsonConsoleLog(json) {
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    console.log('friend: ' + friends[i]);
  };
};

getJSON();

var friends = myJSON[0].friends;

function myFn1(){
  for(var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {    
    main[i].innerHTML = friends[i].id;
  };
};

function myFn2(){
  for(var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {    
    main_div[i].innerHTML = friends[i].name;
  };
};

main.innerHTML = myFn1();
sec.innerHTML = myFn2();
```

Answer (score 1):

you're calling `getJSON` **without** the callback parameter - therefore, the local variable `jsonConsoleLog` is undefined in `getJSON`

snip ...

```
function blah(json) { // changed name to avoid confusion in the answer - you can keep the name you had
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    console.log('friend: ' + friends[i]);
  };
};

getJSON(blah); // change made here (used the function name blah as changed above

var friends = myJSON[0].friends;

function myFn1(){
  for(var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {    
    main[i].innerHTML = friends[i].id;
  };
};
```

snip...

The issue with

```
var friends = myJSON[0].friends;
```

is duplicated here many many times ... `$.getJSON` is **asynchronous** and you are trying to use it **synchronously**

i.e. when you assign `var friends = myJSON[0].friends;` `myJson` hasn't been assigned in `$.getjson` ... in fact, `$.getjson` hasn't even BEGUN to run

here's all your code reorganised and rewritten to hopefully work

```
var main = document.getElementsByClassName('main');
var sec = document.getElementsByClassName('sec');

function getJSON(callback) {
    $.getJSON('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cpldILZRfm?   indent=2', function(json) {
        if (json != null) {
            console.log('Load Successfull!');
        };
        if (callback) {
            callback(json);
        }
    });
};

function doThings(json) {
    var friends = json[0].friends;
    for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
        console.log('friend: ' + friends[i]);
    };
    function myFn1() {
        for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
            main[i].innerHTML = friends[i].id;
        };
    };

    function myFn2() {
        for (var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
            main_div[i].innerHTML = friends[i].name;
        };
    };

    main.innerHTML = myFn1();
    sec.innerHTML = myFn2();
}

getJSON(doThings);
```

Comment: That actually seems to have worked. Thanks. I've upwoted Your answer for now, prolly will mark it as correct, but want to wait and see if anybody got any idea abot second part of my issue.

Comment: I've added answer for the second part - if that were the only part you got wrong, I probably would've flagged this as duplicate, as the issue is one that is asked about once per hour

Comment: Yes, I know it's async, but isn't the callback function precisely for that? I mean, I thought the whole point of building and using callback was to ensure that $.getJSON will get executed before any other part of the code?

Comment: yes it is - but you assigned to `var friends` **synchronously** so damage was done

Comment: The point of the callback isn't that it will be executed before any other part of the code.  The point is that it will be executed whenever the HTTP request (in your case, for some JSON) has finished.  But the rest of the code - starting with your assignment - will carry on executing as soon as your `getJSON` function finishes (which isn't the same as when the `jQuery` call to `getJSON` finishes).

Comment: @roonroon - I've rewritten **all** your code - I think what I've done should work ... I've renamed some functions just so there's no confusion

Comment: Thanks, seen that. Actually I did eventually came up with very similiar sollution on my own, but as promissed - I marked your answer as correct and - additionally - i will post my way too.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is because your function `getJSON` is expecting one formal argument, which you've called `jsonConsoleLog`.  But you are not passing any arguments to `getJSON`.  This means that inside `getJSON` the formal parameter, `jsonConsoleLog`, will indeed be undefined.  Note that because you've named the formal parameter `jsonConsoleLog`, which is the same name as the function you're hoping to call, inside `getJSON` you won't have access to the function.  What you need to do is pass the function as the parameter:

`getJSON(jsonConsoleLog);`

The second problem is I think to do with the `json` variable - it doesn't have a property `0` (i.e. the error is occurring when you try to treat it as an array and access element 0), which suggets that `json` is coming back empty, or is not an array.

Comment: Thank You. So, do you have any idea how to get rid of the json problem? I don't really understand what happens there - json is supposed to be a form of an array, isn't it?

Comment: What data are you expecting `json` to be?  Easiest way forward is just to print that to the console.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the second problem - looks like Jaromanda has nailed that issue in his edit.

Answer (score 0):

Correct, fully working code (basically the same as accepted, correct answer but stylistycally bit different)

```
var main = document.getElementsByClassName('main');
var sec = document.getElementsByClassName('sec');
var friends = null;

function getJSON(jsonConsoleLog){
  $.getJSON('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cpldILZRfm?indent=2', function(json){
    if (json != null){
        console.log('Load Successfull!');
    };
    if (jsonConsoleLog){
        jsonConsoleLog(json[0].friends);
    }       
  });   
};

function jsonConsoleLog(json) {
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    console.log('friend: ' + json[i]);

  };
  friends = json;
  myFn1();
  myFn2();
  };

function myFn1(){
  for(var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {    
    main[i].innerHTML = friends[i].id;
  };
};

function myFn2(){
  for(var i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {    
    main[i].innerHTML += friends[i].name;
  };
};

getJSON(jsonConsoleLog);
```